# Link error duplicate symbol

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

This error is only produced when the scheme set to Distribution and not Debug. Any ideas?

> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_TouchTrailLayer in
>   /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flashlight-gmurejxadxglkncisufsozykekdz/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/libcocos2d
>   libraries.a(TouchTrailLayer.o) and
>   /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flashlight-gmurejxadxglkncisufsozykekdz/Build/Intermediates/Flashlight.build/Distribution-iphoneos/Flashlight.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TouchTrailLayer.o
>   for architecture armv7
>
> Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++
>   failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've included `cocos2d`'s source files in your project but also linked against `libcocos2dlibraries`. You should remove the source files for `cocos2d` from your project if you're linking to the `.a`.

Comment: Sweet! Finally! Thanks darvidsOn